# How do I completely remove ekiga?

Tags: uninstall, ekiga

How do I completely remove ekiga via sudo `apt-get remove --purge` seems to leave some information when i re-install ekiga. can i rm -rvf even tho ekiga is not just in the home file but in the gconf>apps file?

The reason is that I had added two profiles (A & B) but after trying remove --purge the other profile (B) is still there but not visible from computer 1... I installed ekiga on another ubuntu computer 2 with (B) profile. When I try message (B) from computer 1 it goes nowhere because it apparently is sending it to profile (A) on computer 1. However sending from comp 2 with profile (B) to comp 1 and profile (A) it goes through.  So it is apparent comp 1 has profiles (A) and (B) even after remove --purge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove configuration files completely](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20127/how-to-remove-configuration-files-completely)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**apt-get purge** won't get rid of local configuration files.
ekiga creates files in your home directory, under
`./.gconf/apps/ekiga`

You'll have to delete that entire directory with `rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/ekiga`

Applications frequently use `.gconf`, `.gnome*`, `.config` and `.local` for various settings and cache information, so those are good places to check in general.

If you're not finding more pieces of ekiga, try running `sudo updatedb` and when that finishes, try `locate ekiga` .  You might find something you've missed.

From the additional items, you've added, I don't see any problems.  If you really wanted to you could delete some of those items with something like `sudo rm /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/scripts/apps/ekiga/script.pyc` .  I wouldn't expect these to make a difference, unless you're using orca.

Comment: I have deleted that file manually before but to no avail. thank you, but hopefully there might be another way?

Comment: If you've deleted that entire directory, try using the `sudo updatedb` and `locate` method for another try.

Comment: using locate found:/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/orca/scripts/apps/ekiga
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/orca/scripts/apps/ekiga/__init__.py
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/scripts/apps/ekiga/__init__.py
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/scripts/apps/ekiga/script.pyc
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/ekiga.desktop
/usr/share/pyshared/orca/scripts/apps/ekiga/__init__.py
/usr/share/pyshared/orca/scripts/apps/ekiga/script.py
and others but they are just icons. But I cannot delete them. any help with this? thanks

Comment: Those likely aren't causing issues, but you should be able to delete them with `sudo rm` .

Comment: ok i will try that, but umm how? just sudo rm ekiga ?

Comment: I've added a little more info to the answer.