# How do i completely uninstall tor? (and then install it?)

Tags: 11.04, tor

First of all, I'm really new to Ubuntu and Tor. I've been trying to get tor working for days now and I can't seem to do it. Right now I'm trying to remove all remnants of tor/vidalia/polipo from my computer so I can start fresh again.

I've uninstalled vidalia and tor from the software center, but there's still two folders in the /etc directory (privoxy and polipo). Does this mean that these programs are still installed? If not, can I just delete the directory and how would I do that? I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 17):

To remove the configuration files, re-install tor and polipo, then purge them (remove removes the application, but leaves the system configuration files.

```
sudo apt-get purge tor polipo
```

From the [apt-get man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/apt-get.8.html)

**purge**

> purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
>   purged (any configuration files are deleted too).

Comment: Also refer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/20127/how-to-remove-configuration-files-completely for removal of configuration files in your homefolder since files created by the programs themselves won't be touched by `apt-get purge`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this command line, it succeded for me!

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge tor-browser
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for those that the previous answers did not:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge tor
```

Comment: I do not see any diffrence from other answers.