# How to remove unwanted configuration files/folders?

Tags: uninstall

When installing an application it creates few files/folder, mostly in `HOME` `~/.config` and `~/.local/share/`.

After removing the application these files do not automatically get removed. So, is there a way to **remove all the files related to a removed app**?

PS: [How to remove configuration files completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20127/) <- I've read this question but it suggests removing the files one-by-one for each application. I am looking for a way to remove all these files in one step, if there's any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu Tweak 0.6.x series has introduced some new features like: Unity-specific settings and tweaks,   **a built-in Computer Janitor**   , options to change the theme, icons, fonts and more.

> To install the latest Ubuntu Tweak 0.6, use the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Or [download it](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/+download) from Launchpad.

---

[image: Ubuntu Tweak]

[image: Ubuntu Tweak]

Comment: Ahh! Ubuntu Tweak. Why did it never occur to me lol. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Also worth trying, athough the log files and the files and the user-folder do not get deleted:

```
sudo dpkg --purge $(COLUMNS=200 dpkg -l | grep "^rc" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```

Read more here: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/8269-ubuntu-cleaning-up-configuration-residue-packages