# How should I remove or empty these files or folders?

Tags: command-line, files

Below are the instructions that I need to carry out:

```
1. Navigate to the Symantec AntiVirus virus definitions directory (default location is: `/opt/Symantec/virusdefs`) in the terminal.
2. Remove any `*.tmp` or `temp` files or folders.
3. Remove any numbered folders.
4. Ensure that the 3 remaining folders are empty. If they are not empty, empty them.
- `binhub` (expected to be full).
- `incoming` (usually empty, if it's not, this may be an indication of what is wrong).
- `texthub` (also usually empty).
```

Question #1: What specific commands must I issue to remove the `tmp` or `temp` files/folders?

Question #2: What specific commands must I issue to empty `binhub`, `incoming` and `texthub`?

Question #3: I noticed that if I click on the Home Folder icon on the Launcher, then click File System, navigate to the destination foler, I can see the `tmp`, `temp` and  numbered folders. Can I right click on each of them and choose “Move to Trash”? Is this method equivalent to your answer to Question #1?

As always, detailed explanations are welcome for newbies like me.

**UPDATE #1**:

In answer to my own Question #3: the method doesn't work as

(a) There is no "Move to Trash" option after right-clicking the folder. The folders contain many files.

(b) All the folders named in the preceding paragraph need root permission.

(c) Conclusion: no choice but to remove non-empty folders using a Terminal window with the following command:

```
sudo rmdir -rfv <foldername>
```

The above command successfully remove all the non-empty folders.

**UPDATE #2**:

I am stuck at emptying folders, viz. definfo.dat and usage.dat. Please see below:

```
sharon@sharon:/opt/Symantec/virusdefs$ sudo echo > definfo.dat
bash: definfo.dat: Permission denied
sharon@sharon:/opt/Symantec/virusdefs$ sudo echo > usage.dat
bash: usage.dat: Permission denied
sharon@sharon:/opt/Symantec/virusdefs$ sudo cat
[sudo] password for sharon:
```

Comment: There's no reason to create two posts for the same question. If you need to modify your question, there's an `Edit` button.

Comment: @ voithos: No offense and certainly no intention of spamming. I waited for my first post to appear. After waiting for about 10 minutes when it did not show up, I re-posted it.

Comment: @ Tom Brossman: I haven't tried anything yet; I'm afraid of messing things up and then I'd have to reinstall the program. Even worse I might've to reinstall the whole Ubuntu OS. That was what happened to me last week and I'd to reinstall the OS because I didn't know the specific commands to remove the entire messed-up program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove configuration files completely](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20127/how-to-remove-configuration-files-completely)

Comment: @ Rick Green: Sorry, but my post is not a duplicate. It contains other stuff as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have just answered all my questions.

In my edited post, I mentioned in Update #1 that I was able to remove non-empty folders.

Now, in this post (or rather my own answer to my earlier post), I was able to empty the contents of the 2 files, viz.  definfo.dat and usage.dat:

```
sharon@sharon:~$ cd /opt/Symantec/virusdefs
sharon@sharon:/opt/Symantec/virusdefs$ sudo gedit definfo.dat
[sudo] password for sharon: 
sharon@sharon:/opt/Symantec/virusdefs$ sudo gedit usage.dat
```

**All I need now is for some expert on Linux and Ubuntu to confirm that my actions are orthodox and correct so that I will commit them to memory. To summarize:**

1. To remove non-empty folders, one has to issue the command:

   `sudo rmdir -rfv <foldername>`
2. To empty the contents of a file such as *.dat, issue the following command:

   `sudo gedit usage.dat`

gedit window pops up with the contents. I used the "backspace" key to delete the contents and clicked the "Save" icon on the gedit menu bar at the top to save and close the file.