# How to completely remove PlayOnLinux on 14.04 Ubuntu?

Tags: playonlinux, cd

I was trying to install PlayOnLinux from terminal but it failed 2 but the last time it installed but I couldn't agree. But it worked and installed. I installed the latest version. Here is the problem, I start the program PlayOnLinux and I press install program, the " Install a non listed game" my issue is machine is not showing the exe files nothing shows up for the CD Drive no files found, I browse the CD no files on CD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type These commands in Terminal:-

```
sudo apt-get purge playonlinux  
sudo apt-get autoremove  
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

After that, there is still something left to do. Go to your hidden folders in `/home/.playonLinux`, which is where the settings are for POL. After deleting a program, the settings folder stays if you don't delete it manually.

Comment: Here is a way how to remove configuration files as well : http://askubuntu.com/questions/20127/how-to-remove-configuration-files-completely

Comment: Thank you. Does Ubuntu Linux see the files on a CD, because my computer does not see the files? M

Answer (score 0):

This one command will remove wine and playonlinux completely.

```
sudo apt purge wine* playonlinux* && sudo apt autoremove && rm -r ~/.wine ~/.playonlinux
```

Also there can be .deb files of wine and playonlinux in `/var/cache/apt/archives` which you can remove by `apt clean` and  there can be some files of Those dos apps which can be left behind like saved game ..etc. You have remove those manually .