# Openshot VideoEditor is not running

Tags: 16.04, openshot

[image]

not able to run the openshot. Everytime, I run it it goes and create a process though. Even after ending process and restarting doesnot work, then running through terminal, gave me above mentioned error.[Above attached photo].

Comment: First I highly suggest you file a bug report on this. Second, try `rm -rf ~/.openshot`

Comment: I tried re-installing after removing and its coming again.

Comment: re-installilng will not help as removing, purging, and / or reinstalling does not remove configuration files in your home directory. Try `rm -rf ~/.openshot`

Comment: n What did you exactly did. Will u please explain a little.

Comment: It removed a corrupt configuration file.

Comment: What does -rf mean and also ~/.openshot (does this way is tell that its a configuration file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many programs, including openshot, store user settings in your home directory.

These user configuration files are not removed when you remove programs including the use of the purge option. You have to remove them manually.

In this case

```
rm -rf ~/.openshot
```

openshot will re-create these files next time you start the program.

Hard to know what exactly was corrupted.

See man apt-get for details

> remove
>
> ```
>        remove is identical to install except that packages are removed
>        instead of installed. Note that removing a package leaves its
>        configuration files on the system. If a plus sign is appended to
>        the package name (with no intervening space), the identified
>        package will be installed instead of removed.
>
>    purge
>
>        purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
>        purged (any configuration files are deleted too).
> ```

Note: "configuration files" refers to system files , not user files in home.

See also [How to remove configuration files completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20127/how-to-remove-configuration-files-completely)